# Is [land] tag named well enough?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [land](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land) with 18 questions tagged using it.

Is there a better name that we could use for this tag?

I think there is, and will provide that thought as an answer, but want to give the community a chance to express its thoughts, before I offer it.

Comment: We might also want to fold the property tag into this discussion -- used four times, each time in conjunction with the land tag

Answer (score 2):

I suggest we need [land-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land-records) to cover questions about, sources discussing land acquisition, transfer, inheritance, disputes etc. and [land-practices](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land-practices) to cover things like gavelkind, copyhold, freehold, leasehold, having to have two wills in Jersey -- one for real property and one for the rest...

Comment: My suggestion was going to be [tag:land-records] but I'm happy to get behind both that and [tag:land-practices].

Comment: @PolyGeo we might need a better phrase than land-practices unless we think it won't be interpreted as faming methods :)